# On a Node.js server in a GET request response how to output any data about the user in the console?

Tags: node.js, express

The goal is to make a simple Node server. Create a GET request with a response "Hello World", but also output any data about the user in the console.

Comment: so please show us what you've tried so far...

Comment: A good place to start would be [the official Node documentation that provides a "Hello World!" example](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/getting-started-guide/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, you can create a middleware if you are using ExpressJS:

```
module.exports = async function (req, res, next) {
    req.user = {id: 1, name: "John Doe"}
    next()
}
```

and then add this middleware into your request:

```
const userMiddleware = require('../middleware/userMiddleware')
router.get("/", userMiddleware, function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.user)
})
```

Comment: All the information I got was output any data about the user. I thought that the solution was something common and I wasn't able to find the correct answer. I got as a reply from the tutor that it is appropriate to console log "req.get('user-agent')". This is my first question, I'm glad that I got a clear and quick reply! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic express server that will respond with "Hello World" to any request and console log request object. If you need to log anything in particular, check [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req) that lists all of the properties of request object.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use((req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World');
  console.log(req);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: I agree with that logic. It's the best way to invest time, to learn. Thank you for your answer!